# What's the ngResource “way” of handling a collection pagination

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-headers, ngresource

Creating a User resource class from a angular resource is is good in that way that all users becomes a instans of User. That simplify CRUD to each one individual. But it will only works if the response is a array

Here is a simple demonstration ([inspired by angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource#example))

```
// Define User class
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId: '@id'}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, params: {limit: 25} }
});

// We can retrieve a collection from the server
var users = User.query(function() {
    // GET: /user?limit=25
    // server returns: [ {id:456, name:'jimmy'}, {...} ];

    var user = users[0];
    // each user is an instance of User
    expect(user instanceof User).toEqual(true);
    user.relation = "Single";
    // non GET methods are mapped onto the instances
    user.$save();
});
```

#### Now that you have 1000 of users, what is the best practice to handle pagination?

I have seen many API in my days and this would be an example of them all bulk together. (that even includes a response status 200 OK with another status code and a error message)

```
{
    errors: null,
    status: 200
    data: {
        href: "/user?limit=30&offset=100&online=true",
        offset: 100,
        limit: 25,
        totalItems: 987,
        totalPages: 45, // Math.celi(totalItems / limit)
        currentPage: 4,
        first: { href: "/user?limit=25&online=true" },
        previous: { href: "/user?limit=25&offset=75&online=true" },
        next: { href: "/user?limit=25&offset=125&online=true" },
        last: { href: "/user?limit=25&offset=975&online=true" },
        items: [
            {id: 456, name: "jimmy"}
        ]
    }
}
```

If this would be a public api, would you want all/some of this information to be shipped in the json response? i personally consider this plotted and unnecessary server work that may or may not be used by all users

- a error message should respond with a status code >= 400
- status code is already available on the headers, why have another one?
- the ngResource would just simply work if you would get a array instead of an object without making any response transformation
- every other information is know if you just knew the total amount of users

  - this requires the json to return a object to send that information, but you could also use headers and keep the response as an array

I maybe would want some kind of 206 partial content response using just range request headers, i have only used it for file bytes. but could it also be possible to use any other kind of collection?

```
Range: user=75-100,600- ;get user 75 to 100 and 600 to 978
```

isn't that what 206 is all about?

Comment: Except Range is not meant for that stuff.Range is not "semantic",it has a very specific purpose,serve ranges of bytes of a file,not range of items in an array.Or it would be like using header location for the adress of a record in your database,it doesnt make sense.Even worse,my app/client might be configured to treat range headers a specific way.Use X-Range if you like.

Comment: Dojo has solved this problem in its JsonRestStore api http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/data/JsonRestStore#id7 the advantage of this is that you don't have to do user>75 && user<100 in the url parameters, they respond with the header ´Content-Range: items 0-24/66´

Comment: @mpm Range doesn't have to be just only for bytes it's built extensible to support `Accept-Ranges: other unit`
http://otac0n.com/blog/2012/11/21/range-header-i-choose-you.html